# C++ strange behaviour

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ to say the least. However, I cannot find answer to this specific question anywhere.

This is not code specific either, as I tried downloading a lot of code and compiling it via g++ or just make.

It seems that whenever i include a class header in my `main()` it throws the linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "House::getNumBath()", referenced from:
      printHouse(House) in houses-91268b.o
  "House::getSqft()", referenced from:
      printHouse(House) in houses-91268b.o
  "House::getColor()", referenced from:
      printHouse(House) in houses-91268b.o
  "House::House(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int, double)", referenced from:
      _main in houses-91268b.o
  "House::House()", referenced from:
      _main in houses-91268b.o
  "House::~House()", referenced from:
      _main in houses-91268b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It happens no matter what code do I download or produce and seems to be related to the constructor function implemented as MyClass::MyClass(/* args */);

Someone suggested that I should include `.cpp` file in my `main`  instead of `.h` file, and yes **it works**. But it's very wrong as I've always been taught that interfaces are meant for it. Otherwise what's their purpose?

With another person suggestion (googled), I am now downloading 10GB worth of Xcode, and hope it helps. Still seems like it's not going to work. What is wrong with C++ here? Am I for some reason missing C++ 11 (again, why on the relatively new OS?) ?

**UPDATE:**

I grabbed the code from another tutorial that throws me the same thing:

dog.cc

```
  #include "Dog.h"


  Dog::Dog() {


  }
```

dog.h

```
  #ifndef DOG_H
  #define DOG_H


  class Dog {
       public:
          Dog();
       protected:
       private:

  };

  #endif
```

main.cc

```
   #include "Dog.h"


   int main() {

     Dog barky;

     return 0;

 }
```

Throws both the same after me doing (they are in the same folder, those):

```
g++ main.cc
```

or

```
make ./main
```

It is probably the simplest example I wanted to try, as I never had problems like this before in C, either using `Makefile` or by just `cc` the file.

Comment: Are you able to compile and link the smallest c++ program? `int main() { }`

Comment: yes, it is possible. as long as i don't do MyClass::MyClass() / call the constructor

Comment: Show us your House class definition and implementation and your MyClass definition and implementation.

Comment: actually this particular code i downloaded from Lynda.com lessons, some reason it throws this, however i am now updating the question by writing the minimal exmaple which doesnt work

Comment: To me this sounds like an issue with your build system? The error you are showing usually arises when your linker does not know where to find the object files that the compiler produced. Make sure that your linker search paths are pointing to the directory where the object files are stored. Without knowing more about the build system you are using the true issue is still unclear

Comment: Could be build system, but could you edit your question to include your compiler and linker command lines?

Comment: updated the initial post

Comment: So what about `g++ main.cc dog.cc`. How does Makefile look like?

Comment: It was the Makefile/build issue, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the object (dog.o) file first:

```
g++ -c dog.cc
```

Then compile the main with it:

```
g++ main.cc dog.o
```

Comment: Or just compile both .cc files at the same time, or use a Makefile to manage the compilation process...

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that 99% of the tutorials out there use Visual Studio or Eclipse that does that for you. Both of which, IDEs, i refuse to use for some time at least.

In the end, hardly anyone explains the proper steps.

I am a simple text editor user (VIM/tmux or Sublime text), and this doesn't happen automagically when using neither of these (obviously).